# Data can't fetch from db - mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using the Mockito framework for my jUnit testing.
I am not able to fetch data from the database. Fetches null or empty from the db. Not sure how can I mock the entityManager.

```
public class AppServiceTest  {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;    
    @Mock 
    DataSource mockDataSource;
    @Mock 
    Connection mockConn;
    @Mock 
    PreparedStatement mockPreparedStmnt;
    @Mock 
    ResultSet mockResultSet;    
    @Mock
    private Query query;

    @Test
    public void testGetAllDc() throws NamingException {        

        AppDataService appDataService  = Mockito.mock(AppDataService.class); 
        List<String> customResults = new ArrayList<String>();
        //customResults = ....
        System.out.println("**RESULTS**"+appDataService.getAllDc());              // here it is printed as []
        Mockito.when(appDataService.getAllDc()).thenReturn(customResults);
        }
    }
```

AppDataService.java:

```
@Stateless
public class AppDataService{

   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager entityManager;

     public List<Object> getAllDc() {
       try {
         Query query = entityManager.createQuery("myQuery");
         List<String> allDc= query.getResultList();
         }
         //......   
   }
```

Update:
Its observed that the mock values can be detected for entityManager as `Mock for EntityManager, hashCode: 5425710`. But `entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()` or whatever `entityManager.get....()` are getting null in the AppDataService class .

Comment: is it just me or you are trying to mock every class in the test? 
is this a unit test or an integration test?
if unit test, have you tried with DBUnit?

Comment: I am new to junit. I need to test my DAO methods. Do we need to hit the database in the test method as well to make sure that the db fetch is working properly.

Comment: Cool. So if you need to test your DAO methods, mock the DB with DBunit. That will run much faster than connecting with the real thing, allowing the dev team to write code and test it, and also you won't depend on the state of an external resource to make your unit tests pass, which is extremely helpful. Then the next step will be integration tests, running in a properly configured environment.

Answer (score 2):

In your test, you create a mock `AppDataService appDataService  = Mockito.mock(AppDataService.class);`.

In order to test **this class**, you **must not** mock it. Either create it using `new AppDataService()` or let mockito do that for you (`@InjectMocks`)

To initialize the mocks or the class-under-test you may do this by using annotations and either use the mockito runner:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class AppServiceTest  {

   @InjectMock
   private AppService appService;

   @Mock
   private EntityManager entityManager;
```

or

```
@Before
public void setup() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Further, you mocked entitymanager, therefore all of it's methods are stubbed and return no values (null) per default on any method call.

If you expect the `createQuery("myQuery")` invocation to return something, you should stub it properly after mock creation/injection in the setup method.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
  //... 
  when(entityManager.createQuery(eq("myQuery"))).thenReturn(query); 
  //OR
  when(entityManager.createQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(query)
```

If it doesn't matter what the mocks return as long as it is not null, you may initialize the mocks using

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)) //OR @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

So the whole test should look like

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class AppServiceTest  {

  @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)) 
  private EntityManager entityManager;    
  @Mock
  private Query query;

  ...
  @InjectMocks
  private AppDataService appDataService;

  @Test
  public void testGetAllDc() throws NamingException {        

     //arrange
     List<String> customResults = new ArrayList<String>();
     //TODO populate customResults
     when(entityManager.createQuery("myQuery")).thenReturn(query);
     when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(customResults);

     //act
     System.out.println("**RESULTS**"+appDataService.getAllDc());
```

Comment: try `when(entityManager.createQuery(eq("myQuery"))).thenReturn(query)` or `when(entityManager.createQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(query)` and if you use @InjectMocks and @Mock annotations, run the test with `MockitoJUnitRunner` or invoked MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) before configuring the mocks

Comment: Thanks. Its observed that the mock values can be detected for `entityManager` as `Mock for EntityManager, hashCode: 5425710`. But `entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()` or whatever `entityManager.get....()` are getting null in the `AppDataService` class . Any idea what is missing.

Comment: either you have to declare the behaviour of *every single method* that you intend to invoke, using the `when(...` method. You might as well initialize the mock with deep stubs (`@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)`) or mocks (`@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS)`), and then only inject special behavior where needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mock `appDataService` if you want to test it. This field should be annotated with `@InjectMocks`.

```
@InjectMocks
private AppDataService appDataService = new AppDataService();
```

What you need to mock is `entityManager.createQuery` and `query.getResultList` methods.

```
Query queryMock = mock(Query.class);
when(entityManager.createQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(queryMock);
when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(customResults);
```

After taht you can call `appDataService.getAllDc()` in your test and check the results.

Comment: In this case the `appDataService.getAllDc()` is returning the elements in `customResults`.

Comment: Yes, if there is no extra logic in this method.

Comment: @ep what is the expected behaviour? What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: I needed to test if the db fetch/persist/delete etc. is working properly. I thought there would be an actual db hit happens in a unit test case as well.

Comment: In this case you need integration test with a real connection to DB. No mocking needed here.

Comment: So DAO methods can be tested with integration tests only?

Comment: No only, but if you want to test how your code works in connection with DB, then integration tests is the best option for me.